# Sklearn or Pandas, impute missing values with simple linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-mining

i have data, time series data, and i want to impute the missing data. i cant use mean of the column because i think it's not good for time series data.
so i want simple linear regression to impute it

```
Day, Price
 1 , NaN
 2, NaN
 3, 1800
 4, 1900
 5, NaN
 6, NaN
 7, 2000
 8, 2200
```

How to do this ?

i prefer to do this using Pandas, 
but if there is no other way i'm ok to do it using sklearn :)

Comment: Check out [imputing of missing values in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#impute)

Comment: @VivekKumar sklearn's imputation supports only constant value, mean, median or most frequent. So, exactly what OP does *not* want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using `interpolate`:

```
df['Price'].interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
    Price   Date
0   NaN     1
1   NaN     2
2   1800.000000     3
3   1900.000000     4
4   1933.333333     5
5   1966.666667     6
6   2000.000000     7
7   2200.000000     8
```

As you can see, this only fills the missing values in a forward direction. If you want to fill the first two values as well, use the parameter `limit_direction="both"`:

```
df['Price'].interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True, limit_direction="both")
```

There are different interpolation methods, e.g. quadratic or spline, for more info see the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html